# Summary of data for each month

Tags: python, pandas

I do have health diagnosis data for last year and I did like get count of diagnosis for each month. Here is my data:

```
import pandas as pd

cars2 = {'ID': [22,100,47,35,60],
    'Date': ['2020-04-11','2021-04-12','2020-05-13','2020-05-14', '2020-06-15'],
        'diagnosis': ['bacteria sepsis','bacteria sepsis','Sepsis','Risk sepsis','Neonatal sepsis'],
        'outcome': ['alive','alive','dead','alive','dead']
        
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(cars2, columns = ['ID','Date', 'diagnosis', 'outcome'])

print (df2)
```

How can I get diagnosis counts for each month. Example is how many diagnosis of bacteria sepsis we had for that month. Final result is a table showing value counts of diagnosis for each month

Comment: "Summary" is a generic word for descriptive statistics.. Do you want to achieve a particular result (such as your example) or is it more general? What should your desired output look like?

Comment: @Ric Hi, I have gone into specific area. I did like to get value counts of diagnosis for each month

Comment: do you want to count the occurences of each `outcome` as well?

Comment: Including expected output in your question can really improve the quality of answer by clarifying what shape you expect your result to take.

Comment: @meowulf yes, outcome too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your dataframe by setting the `Date` column as index:

```py
import pandas as pd

cars2 = {'ID': [22,100,47,35,60],
    'Date': ['2020-04-11','2021-04-12','2020-05-13','2020-05-14', '2020-06-15'],
        'diagnosis': ['bacteria sepsis','bacteria sepsis','Sepsis','Risk sepsis','Neonatal sepsis'],
        'outcome': ['alive','alive','dead','alive','dead']
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(cars2, columns = ['ID','Date', 'diagnosis', 'outcome'])
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) # <--- I set your Date column as the index (also convert it to datetime)
df2.drop('Date',inplace=True, axis=1) # <--- Drop the Date column
print (df2)
```

if you `groupby` the dataframe by a [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and the columns you want to group with (`diagnosis` and `outcome`):

```py
df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'diagnosis','outcome']).count()
```

Output:

```
                                    ID
Date       diagnosis       outcome    
2020-04-30 bacteria sepsis alive     1
2020-05-31 Risk sepsis     alive     1
           Sepsis          dead      1
2020-06-30 Neonatal sepsis dead      1
2021-04-30 bacteria sepsis alive     1
```

Note: the `freq='M'` in `pd.Grouper` groups the dataframe by month. Read more about the `freq` attribute [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

Edit: Assigning the grouped dataframe to `new_df` and resetting the other indices except `Date`:

```py
new_df = df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'diagnosis','outcome']).count()
new_df.reset_index(level=[1,2],inplace=True)
```

Iterate over each month and get the table separately inside `df_list`:

```py
df_list = [] # <--- this will contain each separate table for each month
for month in np.unique(new_df.index):
    df_list += [pd.DataFrame(new_df.loc[[month]])]
df_list[0] # <-- get the first dataframe in df_list
```

will return:

```
                  diagnosis outcome  ID
Date                                   
2020-04-30  bacteria sepsis   alive   1
```

Comment: Is it possible to loop and have the tables of each month separately so that I can export to slideshow?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see results per month, you can use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

```
df2.pivot_table(index=['outcome','diagnosis'], columns=pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.month, aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
```

---

```
Date                     4  5  6
outcome diagnosis               
alive   Risk sepsis      0  1  0
        bacteria sepsis  2  0  0
dead    Neonatal sepsis  0  0  1
        Sepsis           0  1  0
```

4,5,6 are the months in your dataset.

Try playing around with the parameters here, you might be able to land on a better view that suits your ideal result better.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a `month` variable through [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime) function; then you can group by the month and make a [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html?highlight=value_counts#pandas.Series.value_counts) within the month

```
import pandas as pd

df2['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.month
df2.groupby('month').apply(lambda x: x['diagnosis'].value_counts())

month                 
4      bacteria sepsis    2
5      Risk sepsis        1
       Sepsis             1
6      Neonatal sepsis    1
Name: diagnosis, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean by ***for each month*** is not only mean **month** figure only, but **year-month** combination.  As such, let's approach as follows:

First, we create a 'year-month' column according to the `Date` column.  Then use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on this new `year-month` column and get [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on column `diagnosis`, as follows:

```
df2['year-month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m")
df2.groupby('year-month')['diagnosis'].value_counts().to_frame(name='Count').reset_index()
```

Result:

```
  year-month        diagnosis  Count
0    2020-04  bacteria sepsis      1
1    2020-05      Risk sepsis      1
2    2020-05           Sepsis      1
3    2020-06  Neonatal sepsis      1
4    2021-04  bacteria sepsis      1
```